# Problem finding the inequality for an inner product contatining a dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am having some trouble with the following inequality given as part of a proof in a paper I am reading,

$$(\textbf b \cdot \nabla \phi, \phi)_{L^2} \le \| \textbf b \|_{L^\infty} \|\nabla \phi\|_{L^2} \|\phi \|_{L^2}. $$

Where $\textbf b$ is some constant vector, $\phi$ is some function and $(\cdot , \cdot )_{L^2}$ is the standard inner product with the associated norm. It looks like it should be an application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I can't see how the dot product $\textbf b \cdot \nabla \phi$ is dealt with.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: They applied Cauchy's inequality, and then replaced each component of $b$, in $\|b\cdot \nabla \phi\|_2$ by $\|b\|_\infty$. (Interesting! The first norm in my monitor looks blue and the second looks red).

Comment: @user85667 thanks for the reply, thats a great help.

Comment: What is the definition of $\left\|\nabla\phi\right\|_{L^2}$?

Comment: You could also use Hoelder inequality